# Kmeans function - Amap package - what nstart stands for

Tags: r, data-mining, k-means

I don't understand what the *nstart* changes in the algorithm.

If `centers = 8`, that means the function will cluster 8 groups. But, what *nstart* variates?

This is the explanation on the documentation:

```
centers:    
Either the number of clusters or a set of initial cluster centers. If the first, a random set of rows in x are chosen as the initial centers.

nstart:
If centers is a number, how many random sets should be chosen?
```

Comment: I guess the algorithm tries several random starts (instead of just one) by drawing "number of centers" rows from the data sets, checks the cluster sum of squares, and proceeds with the best start, resulting in a more stable output?

Comment: This question mask is because you are supposing or it is because you want to comment more friendly? Haha

Comment: hmmm both... :-> You can check the examples section of `?kmeans`, too, and look at the source code by entering `kmeans` in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `?kmeans` doesn't exactly explain this (in both `stats` and the `amap` packages). But, one can get an idea by looking at the `kmeans` code.

If one uses more than one random starts (`nstart` greater than 1) for the `kmeans`, then the algorithm returns the **partition that corresponds to the smallest total within-cluster sum of squares.**

(The output contain the total within-cluster sum of squares value as `tot.withinss`).

Answer (score 1):

Look further below in the details:

> The algorithm of Hartigan and Wong (1979) is used by default. Note that some authors use k-means to refer to a specific algorithm rather than the general method: most commonly the algorithm given by MacQueen (1967) but sometimes that given by Lloyd (1957) and Forgy (1965). **The Hartigan–Wong algorithm generally does a better job than either of those, but trying several random starts (nstart> 1) is often recommended.** In rare cases, when some of the points (rows of x) are extremely close, the algorithm may not converge in the “Quick-Transfer” stage, signalling a warning (and returning ifault = 4). Slight rounding of the data may be advisable in that case.

nstart stand for the number of random starts. I can not explain the statistical details but in their example code, the authors of this function choose 25 random starts:

```
## random starts do help here with too many clusters
## (and are often recommended anyway!):
(cl <- kmeans(x, 5, nstart = 25))
```

Comment: When you mean the number of random starts, is the number of randoms start centroids, right? Isn't this supposed to be the same as the number of centroids, thus, the number in centers?

Comment: The idea is to start clustering from e.g. 5 random centroids. These could be anywhere in the set so theoretically they are close together which is not ideal for a clustering attempt. As far as I understand nstart, the random choice of centroids is made e.g. 25 times in consecutive iterations if you set it that way. See e.g. [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58238/how-random-are-the-results-of-the-kmeans-algorithm).